# Edit an email body using selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium

The editor field already has HTML text within it. 
I want to Clear it using Selenium.

Below is the code of the site.

```
<div id="EmailText" style="display: none">
  <table id="tabbgcol1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="padding: 0px; font: inherit; color: inherit;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top">
          <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" style="color: inherit; font: inherit;">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td id="colcol21">
                  <p>Hello,</p>
                  <p>AS would like your feedback!</p>
                  <p>We thank you for your time and participation.</p> 
                  <p>Sincerely,</p>
                  <p>Saket</p>
                  <p>ZASD</p>
                  <span style="font-size:11px;font-family:Verdana, Arial, san-serif;"></span>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Is it possible to Edit individual paragraphs here. Or should I clear it. I am not able locate the  text field here.

Using this id `id="colcol21"` results in element not found.

Comment: Is it inside `<ifarme>` tag?

Comment: Please add the code you tried and the error message (if you have any).

Comment: Thanks But I solved it. Using id=tabbgcol1 and clearing the whole field. Had to use cssSelector for the id.